# increasing strictly concave function and summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a function f(x) on R, and that f(x) is strictly increasing and strictly concave: f'(x) > 0, and f''(x) <0.
Is it always true that, for such function, we have:

> f(a+b) < f(a) + f(b)

a,b are real numbers.

Comment: It is true if $f(0)\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x) = -e^{-x}$. Then $-e^{-t} = f(0+t)$ is not smaller than $f(0) + f(t) = -1 - e^{-t}$.

Comment: One more question, how will the result change if we restrict f(x) such that f(x) >0 for all value of x on the reals?

Comment: @user360546: Such a function does not exist since the limit as $x \to -\infty$ is $-\infty$ for strictly concave increasing functions.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $f(x)=-1/2^x$, then $f$ is increasing and strictly concave but
$$-\frac{1}{8}=f(1+2)>f(1)+f(2)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}=-\frac{3}{4}.$$
However, if $f(0)\geq 0$ and $f$ is strictly concave in $[0,+\infty)$ then for $a,b>0$
$$f(a)+f(b)=f\left(t\cdot(a+b)+(1-t)\cdot0\right)+f\left((1-t)\cdot(a+b)+t\cdot0\right)\\> t\cdot f\left(a+b\right)+(1-t)\cdot f(0)+(1-t)\cdot f\left(a+b\right)+t\cdot f(0)\\=f(a+b)+f(0)\geq f(a+b)$$
where $t=a/(a+b)\in(0,1)$.